# Creating a hyperlink in the datatable that would redirect to other tab and show the information of selected item

Tags: r, shiny, datatable

I am trying to add an interactive feature in one/multiple columns of a Shiny datatable. Basically, I am trying to create a hyperlink to all the values of a column (say, mpg) for the datatable in tab 1 and get that row data displayed on tab 2. For instance, for the first row of the datatable, the mpg value (21) would be a hyperlink and when you click on 21, it would redirect to tab 2 that would display all the other column values corresponding to that row clicked. Here is a working version of my code. But i am getting an error

My code is here

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(purrr)
```

```
ui <- fluidPage(
   titlePanel("Link in Datatable"),
   tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Table",
               dataTableOutput("tab")),
      tabPanel("Details",
               dataTableOutput("details")),
      id = "ts"
   )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
   orig_data <- reactive({
      mtcars %>%
         rownames_to_column("id")
   })
   
   details <- reactiveVal(NULL)
   
   output$tab <- renderDataTable({
      orig_data() %>% 
         mutate(mpg = imap_chr(mpg,
                               function(mpg, idx) {
                                  actionLink(paste0("to_details_", idx),
                                             mpg) %>% 
                                     as.character()
                               })
         ) %>% 
         datatable(escape = FALSE, 
                   selection = "none", 
                   rownames = FALSE,
                   options = list(
                      preDrawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
                      drawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } ')
                   ))
   })
   
   output$details <- renderDataTable({
      details() %>% 
         datatable()
   })
   
   obs <- lapply(1:nrow(orig_data()), function(idx) {
      observeEvent(input[[paste0("to_details_", idx)]], {
         details(orig_data() %>% 
                    slice(idx))
         updateTabsetPanel(session, "ts", selected = "Details")
      })
   })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

i tried this but getting error

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that in `obs <- lapply(1:nrow(orig_data()), ...)` you are using `orig_data()` outside of a reactive context. One option to fix that would be to wrap in an `observe`r:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(purrr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Link in Datatable"),
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel(
      "Table",
      dataTableOutput("tab")
    ),
    tabPanel(
      "Details",
      dataTableOutput("details")
    ),
    id = "ts"
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  orig_data <- reactive({
    mtcars %>%
      rownames_to_column("id")
  })

  details <- reactiveVal(NULL)

  output$tab <- renderDataTable({
    orig_data() %>%
      mutate(mpg = imap_chr(
        mpg,
        function(mpg, idx) {
          actionLink(
            paste0("to_details_", idx),
            mpg
          ) %>%
            as.character()
        }
      )) %>%
      datatable(
        escape = FALSE,
        selection = "none",
        rownames = FALSE,
        options = list(
          preDrawCallback = JS("function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }"),
          drawCallback = JS("function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } ")
        )
      )
  })

  output$details <- renderDataTable({
    details() %>%
      datatable()
  })

  observe({
    lapply(seq(nrow(orig_data())), function(idx) {
      observeEvent(input[[paste0("to_details_", idx)]], {
        details(orig_data() %>%
          slice(idx))
        updateTabsetPanel(session, "ts", selected = "Details")
      })
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]